# C# String.Compare() acting bizarre

Tags: c#, string

The int output from the `String.Compare(String, String, Boolean)` is opposite from what it should be but not in all cases as it depends upon the particular strings being used. The following code works as stated in the reference docs:

```
String s1 = "abdd";
String s2 = "abcd";

int num = String.Compare(s1, s2);
```

However, if the first string is changed to the following, then the `Compare()` method seems to break as the output is the opposite of what it should be:

```
String s1 = "abCd";
String s2 = "abcd";
```

Changing the first string above should have resulted in a negative integer but instead a positive int was obtained.

Comment: _String.Compare(s1,s2,StringComparison.Ordinal);_ and you will get your negative number

Comment: why do you think it should result in a negative number, *specifically*?

Comment: s1 is less on the sort order and Compare should produce a negative number in the example....

Comment: @Darryl only if you assume that Compare does a byte by byte comparison. But this is not the case unless you ask explicitly for that kind of comparison. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Steve, yes the third argument does produce a negative number, but the docs state that a negative number should be produced without the need for a third argument... At least that is the way I understood them.

Comment: Okay Steve, thanks for the info as I now understand.... I thought maybe a bug was discovered LOL.. Once again, Thanks :)

Comment: At least 999 times out of 1,000, questions like this do not indicate a bug in the framework, but a misunderstanding of how things should actually work by the OP. I'm no saying Microsoft products have no bugs, but unless you're working with a beta version, or just done something incredibly rare and unexpected, chances are it was already done before and tested - so if it was a bug, it was probably already fixed.

Comment: @Zohar Peled .... Yeah I pretty much assumed that as well .... I come from a C++ and javascript background and so I imagine I will come across many more similar things in the course of learning C#.... Thanks a million guys :)